# Sonar - Building Solution With Projects That Have Different Configurations

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm having some trouble with performing analysis on a project, and I'm not quite sure how to work around it.

I am working with an engineer to get one of their applications into Sonar. It's a large solution with many projects as part of it. When I performed a build and Sonar analysis as part of a TFS build, I get the following error:

```
##[error]No analysable projects were found but some duplicate project IDs were found. Possible cause: you are building multiple configurations (e.g. DEBUG|x86 and RELEASE|x64) at the same time, which is not supported by the SonarQube integration. Please build and analyse each configuration individually.
```

I took a look at the configuration management in their solution properties and found that there were some different configurations per project. Most were set up for Debug|Any CPU, but there were a couple set up for Debug|x86 and Dev|Any CPU.

[image: Configuration]

[image: Another Configuration]

I tried building just one particular project by using the MSBuild argument /t:, but still ran into the same thing. I've also tried specifying the configuration and platform as MSBuild arguments, but no luck. Is there any possible way to do the analysis without having to change the configuration of the projects directly?

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use XAML build or new tasks based build?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/C-MSBuildRunner-with-multiple-build-configurations-td5035476.html), SanarQube has no plans at the moment to support multiple configurations in the short term.

You would need to setup a separate single configuration build for the SonarQube analysis.